# Does Location#distanceTo(Location) take Location#getAccuracy() into account?

Tags: android, location

I want to write a `LocationListener` that takes the most accurate and precise recent location as its location.  I'm intending to use this code in my `LocationListener`:

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location.distanceTo(mLocation)>location.getAccuracy()){
            mLocation = location;
        }
    }
```

What I intend this to do is update the location if the user's old location is *outside* the circle of "possible locations" that the new location indicates.  So, for example, if our last measurement was a GPS signal and the new one is a cell tower, and the old location was in range of the cell tower, we don't update; on the other hand, if the cell tower is sufficiently distant, we know the user has moved and record that.

However, the `distanceTo(Location)` function states it returns the *approximate* distance in metres between locations.  Does it already take the accuracy into account?  Will it give me a precise enough figure to let me use in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no, `Location.distanceTo(Location)` does not take `Location.getAccuracy()` value into account when measuring distance.

Here's the actual code from the Android platform that is used to calculate distance for `Location.distanceTo(Location)`:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java#L272

It uses Vincenty's Inverse Formula (http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf - Section 4) based on the given latitude and longitude (accuracy not considered).

As to whether your method of updating the "true" user location will be "precise enough", it really depends on GPS sensitivity, accuracy, and precision, which can vary significantly from device to device.

The accuracy estimate value from `Location.getAccuracy()` can also vary widely depending on the OEM, and typically devices I've seen overestimate accuracy (i.e., the device gives an accuracy value greater than the true accuracy) more than underestimate accuracy.

You might want to check out an app I created "GPS Benchmark" (http://www.gpsbenchmark.com/) which helps quickly benchmark location provider accuracy (GPS and Network) on Android devices, as well as "estimated accuracy" accuracy.  I also co-authored a paper on this topic (http://journals.cambridge.org/repo_A82eaJIy) based on GPS benchmarking results from some Java ME devices, and most of the material is also relevant to Android.

Comment: Thanks for that—from what I can gather determining location is pretty hard to do with absolute certainty, for the reasons you mention and several others (people may switch GPS off, people may be indoors, etc.) so I am OK with this answer.