# Interpreting the Android Location Manager Results

Tags: android, locationmanager

I'm writing my first Android application, and have utilized the Android Location Manager to obtain GPS readings. I a bit confused about the accuracy readings I'm getting. For example:

1. I used a tape to measure out 1000 linear feet between two points.
2. While standing at point A I started the location manager update requests until I received an accuracy of +/- 4 feet.
3. I then hit a button in the app to save that particular location (private var).
4. While the location manager continues to poll I walked the line until I reached point B.
5. Once here I waited for an accuracy reading of +/- 4 feet.
6. I then hit another button which takes that location and performs a distance measurement between the two points i.e.:

   double distance = startLocation.distanceTo(endLocation);
7. The returned distance measurement was 1000.20 feet.

I realize that the returned accuracy measurement from the GPS is constantly fluctuating, but I expected that the distance measurement would at least reflect this somewhat. I was surprised at it's precision in comparison to the accuracy readings.

So my question is should I trust the value from the distance measurement, or take into consideration the accuracy measurement returned from the GPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the API reference for Android location you will see the explanation for the accuracy reading as:

> We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if
>   you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude,
>   and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then there is a 68%
>   probability that the true location is inside the circle.
>
> In statistical terms, it is assumed that location errors are random
>   with a normal distribution, so the 68% confidence circle represents
>   one standard deviation. Note that in practice, location errors do not
>   always follow such a simple distribution.
>
> This accuracy estimation is only concerned with horizontal accuracy,
>   and does not indicate the accuracy of bearing, velocity or altitude if
>   those are included in this Location.
>
> If this location does not have an accuracy, then 0.0 is returned. All
>   locations generated by the LocationManager include an accuracy.

Per this post it looks like getAccuracy and distanceTo() methods do not take each other's measurements into consideration. I would follow the advice in the post and check out the GPS Benchmark application for better information from your specific hardware. Hope this helps!:

[Does Location getAccuracy take distanceTo() into Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354301/does-locationdistancetolocation-take-locationgetaccuracy-into-account)